# how to evenly arrange circles in D3.js and keep equal distance between circumferences

Tags: d3.js

I have a data `var myData1 = [5, 10, 15]` and I want to visualize it with circles.

So, I start with `var mySvg1 = d3.select('body').append('svg')`

The FIRST way to arrange circles is this:

[image: Distance between every center is equal]

Distance between every center is equal, I can achieve it with this code:

```
mySvg1.selectAll('circle').data(myData1).enter().append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d,i){return 100+(i*44)})
    .attr('cy', '55')
    .attr('r', function(d){return d})
```

The SECOND way is this:

[image: Distance between every center is increasing accordingly to the values in array]

Distance between every center is increasing accordingly to the values in array:

```
var myHelp1 = 100
mySvg1.selectAll('circle').data(myData1).enter().append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d,i){
        myHelp1 += d + i*22
        return myHelp1
    })
    .attr('cy', '55')
    .attr('r', function(d){return d})
```

And here is MY QUESTION:

[image: equal distance between circumferences]

How to evenly arrange circles by (still dynamically) keeping equal distance between circumferences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUIC, Here's one way. Let's say,

Gap between diameter endpoints is `gap`, (length of red lines)

`base` is current circle's left diameter point

`base + d` gives you current circle's center

`newbase` is next circle's left diameter point

```js
var myData1 = [5, 10, 15]
var mySvg1 = d3.select('body').append('svg')

var base = 90
var newbase = 90
var gap = 20
mySvg1.selectAll('circle').data(myData1).enter().append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d, i){
      base = newbase
     newbase = newbase + 2*d + gap
     return base + d
      })
    .attr('cy', '55')
    .attr('r', function(d){return d})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/utfk44tL/